# Enable scroll for table while reduce the window size

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a table inside a div. The div have a fixed width. If the content of table(td) is large the table become overflow from div.
Consider my HTML look like

```
<div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Text</th></tr>
        <tr><td>abc</td><td>vvvvvvnvjfdjfjfdjdfjjddjfkjfdjfdkjdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>xyz</td><td>hfhdjhjfdhjhdfjhdfjdfhfdhjfdhjdfhjfd</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

To avoid this issue I use

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;     
}
td{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Now the table is look like

[image].

This is ok. Now I want to resize the window suitable for mobile devices.
  Then the table should look like this

[image]

That is I want to avoid the word-wrap and make the table horizontal scroll.

I want the horizontal scroll only for mobile devices screen.
I can write the css for mobile devices in

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.table-responsive > table {

}
```

Since I use the  `table-layout:fixed;` for table  the scroll property for mobile devices is not working. But I can't remove the  `table-layout:fixed;`    property because this is used for other devices(computer).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution..

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.table-responsive > table {
table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

For mobile devices takes the above css. And for other devices(computer) takes

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;     
}
```

Note: I already have the code for horizontal scroll.